# Have to manually start worker on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, django-celery

In my Procfile I have the following:

```
worker: cd appname && celery -A appname worker -l info  --app=appname.celery_setup:app
```

However, when my app submits a task it never happens, but I think the celery worker is at least sort of working, because

```
heroku logs --app appname
```

every so often gives me one of these:

```
2016-07-22T07:53:21+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=14 sample#load-avg-1m=0.03 sample#load-avg-5m=0.09 sample#load-avg-15m=0.085 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664884.0kB sample#memory-free=13458244.0kB sample#memory-cached=187136kB sample#memory-redis=566800bytes sample#hit-rate=0.17778 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

Also, when I open up bash by running

```
heroku run bash --app appname
```

and then type in

```
cd appname && celery -A appname worker -l info  --app=appname.celery_setup:app
```

It immediately tells me the task has been received and then executes it.  I would like to have this happen without me having to manually log in and execute the command - is that possible?  Do I need a paid account on heroku to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turns out you also have to do

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1 --app appname
```

Or else you won't actually be running a worker.